# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets. Let $U = A \cup B \cup C$ be the universal set. Prove that:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A \subseteq ((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U\setminus B)))$.

I've managed to get to:

$$(x \in A \cap x \in B) \cup (x \in A ∩ (x \in U ∩ \neg(x \in B))$$

using definitions of union, complement  etc. but not sure if this is right ?

Comment: Think of what it means:  all elements are either in B... or not.  So all elements of A are either in B. ... or not.  You can do a proof using distribution.   Or you can do an element by element proof.

Answer (score 1):

By expanding the RHS (remind [The fundamental laws of set algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra)), we get
$$ (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U\setminus B))=((A \cap B) \cup  A) \cap ((A \cap B) \cup(U\setminus B))\\
=(A \cup  A)\cap  (B \cup  A) \cap (A \cup(U\setminus B))\cap
(B \cup(U\setminus B)).$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. Another way. Given $x\in A$, if $x\in B$ then $x\in (A\cap B)$, otherwise $x\in (U\setminus B)$ and $x\in (A \cap(U\setminus B))$. Putting all together
$x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A \cap(U\setminus B))$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap(U\setminus B))=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap(A\cup C))=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cup(A\cap C))=$$
$$=(A\cap B)\cup A=A$$

Answer (score 0):

By one of the distributive laws: $\;(A \cap B) \cup \big(A \cap (U\setminus B)\big)=A \cap \big(B \cup (U \setminus B)\big)=A \cap U = A$